# How to programmatically install zen coding on sublime 2?

Tags: ubuntu, sublimetext2, emmet

I was wondering if there is a programmatically way to install zen coding plugin. I did the research but the only manner I found was through [Sublime Console](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/sublime-text-2-tips-and-tricks/). I'm struggling for this answer but it never shows up.

I'm doing this because I have a [script](https://github.com/waldyr/Sublime-Installer) to install Sublime in Ubuntu, and only installing sublime isn't too good. If I give to users the oportunity to install and configure automatically the zen coding, it will improve the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every plugin for Sublime Text 2 can be installed by simply copying its contents into *Packages* folder (find “Browse Packages...“ menu item in ST2 to get it).

Thus, all you need to do is to clone Zen Coding plugin repo (https://github.com/sublimator/ZenCoding or https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime, the latter may not work yet if you’re on Linux x32) into Packages folder.

Comment: Linux Ubuntu x64 with Sublime 2. The second plugin worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the successor to ZenCoding is Emmet. It has been merged with emmet-sublime: https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime

merge discussion: https://github.com/wbond/package_control_channel/pull/1067#issuecomment-16730933